# How to detect if two paths intersect in android?

Tags: java, android, line, collision, intersection

I'm making a small [sprouts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprouts_(game)) app where the user can draw paths between dots or on the screen with paths. I create arraylists of the coordinates of the paths and then attempt to compare them four points at a time to see if they intersect with paths already drawn. Right now, it isn't detecting any collisions. Here some of my code so far:

```
//ArrayList of the currentPath that is being drawn
ArrayList<float[]> currentPath = new ArrayList<>();
//ArrayList of Paths that have been drawn so far
private ArrayList <ArrayList<float[]>> paths = new ArrayList<>();

public boolean checkPath() {
        if (paths.size() == 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        boolean noCollisions = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < paths.size(); i++) {             //Loop through path array to compare each path
            for (int j = 0; j < paths.get(i).size() - 1; j++) {  //Loop through each path to compare points
                for (int k = 0; k < currentPath.size() - 1; k++) {
                    float end1Y = currentPath.get(k + 1)[1];
                    float start1Y = currentPath.get(k)[1];
                    float start1X = currentPath.get(k)[0];
                    float end1X = currentPath.get(k + 1)[0];

                    float end2Y = paths.get(i).get(j + 1)[1];
                    float start2Y = paths.get(i).get(j)[1];
                    float start2X = paths.get(i).get(j)[0];
                    float end2X = paths.get(i).get(j + 1)[0];

                    double A1 = end1Y - start1Y;
                    double B1 = start1X - end1X;
                    double C1 = A1 * start1X + B1 + start1Y;

                    double A2 = end2Y - start2Y;
                    double B2 = start2X - end2X;
                    double C2 = A2 * start2X + B2 * start2Y;

                    double det = (A1 * B2) - (A2 * B1);
                    if (det == 0) {
                        //Lines are either parallel, are collinear or overlapping partially
                        if ((A1 * start2X) + (B1 * start2Y) == C1) {
                            //they are the on the same line, check if they are in the same space
                            if ((Math.min(start1X, end1X) < start2X) && (Math.max(start1X, end1X) > start2X)) {
                                noCollisions = false;
                            }
                            //one end point is okay, now checking the other
                            if ((Math.min(start1X, end1X) < end2X) && (Math.max(start1X, end1X) > end2X)) {
                                noCollisions = false;
                            } else{
                                noCollisions = true;
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        //Lines intersect somewhere, but do the segments intersect?
                        double x = (B2 * C1 - B1 * C2) / det;
                        double y = (A1 * C2 - A2 * C1) / det;

                        //check to see if the intersection is within the bounding box of the segments.
                        if((x > Math.min(start1X, end1X) && x < Math.max(start1X, end1X)) && (y > Math.min(start1Y, end1Y) && y < Math.max(start1Y, end1Y))){
                            //We are within the bounding box of the first line segment, now check the second
                            if((x > Math.min(start2X, end2X) && x < Math.max(start2X, end2X)) && (y > Math.min(start2Y, end2Y) && y < Math.max(start2Y, end2Y))){
                                //the segments intersect
                                noCollisions = false;
                            }
                        } else {
                            noCollisions = true;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        return noCollisions;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use matrices and determinantes to figure out if there is any intersection occurring.

Comment: You should first tell how you can determine an intersection. After that present the code for that.

Comment: I'm determining if there is an intersection by solving the system of equations of the currentPath and each of the past paths in the path array. I pull two points from the currentPath and compare the line they make to every line in each past path.

Comment: Solving a system of equations looks to me a too big word. But comparing line pieces is ok. Please explain how you determine if two line-pieces-s intersect.

Comment: Please give two examples. The first one with two line pieces which do not cross. The second one that do. Tell what your code delivers.

Comment: I don't see a break statement in your loops in case you determine a crossing of lines. You can stop then i think. Please explain.

Comment: i'd advice you use integral coordinates instead of floating points then use a kd tree to find the nearest coordinates to any newly added points.

Answer (score 1):

Ain't this easier?

```
Region region1, region2;
boolean intersect;

Region clip = new Region(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
region1.setPath(path1, clip);
region2.setPath(path2, clip);

if (!region1.quickReject(region2))
 intersect = true;
else intersect = false;
```

(I know I'm late)

Answer (score 0):

Please try to replace below line

```
double C1 = A1 * start1X + B1 + start1Y;
```

by following line

```
double C1 = A1 * start1X + B1 * start1Y;
```